# HTML has a margin bigger than body

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm creating my own personal site using bootstrap.

I've using bootstrap4 with some modifications. However the html margin is bigger than body.
I've already checked other questions and they say that `<p>` or some other tag has a default margin and you need to zero that, however I'm using a reset.css and plus I tried to zero margin of a lot of elements and it didn't work.

the reset css and the link to my web site: https://sitezinho--mateusmsouza.repl.co/

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

and HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Mateus Machado - Site Pessoal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/custom.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" href="public/js/jquery-3.4.0.min.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='public/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'>

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <main role="main">
        <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="background-color: black">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link text-light px-5">Hello World</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-light px-5">Projetos</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-light px-5">Material de Estudo</a></li>


            </ul>

            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto>
          <li class=" nav-item active "> <a href="http://github.com/mateusmsouza " class="nav-link "><img src="GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png "> </a></li>
        </ul>

      </nav>

    <section class="my-4 " >
      <div class="content ">
        <h1 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center ">printf("Olar ");</h1>

        <p class="lead grey-text text-center w-responsive mx-auto mb-5 ">Me chamo Mateus Machado, trabalho atualmente como Software Tester, graduando em Tecnologia de Banco de Dados. Desenvolvo para projetos pessoais no tempo livre e no tempo mais livre toco violão e faço outras coisas de humano :)</p>

        <div class="container-fluid px-5 py-5 " style="background-color:grey ";>
          <div class="row container-fluid " ">
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="img/magogenteboa.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="col-7 container-fluid">
              <ul>
                <li style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3)" class="px-3 py-3 my-1">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img/baseline_school2.png">
                   <p class="text-light">Técnico em Redes de Computadores pela 
                     <a href="http://etecjbento.com.br/web/" class="acustom">Etec Cônego José Bentos</a> 
                    </p>
                  <small class="text-light font-italic">Período: 2016 - 2017</small>

                <li style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3)" class="px-3 py-3 my-1">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img/baseline_school2.png">
                  <p class="text-light">Graduando em Tecnologia de Banco de Dados pela <a  href="http://fatecsjc-prd.azurewebsites.net/" class="acustom">Fatec São José dos Campos</a> </p>
                  <small class="text-light font-italic">Período: 2018 - Atualmente</small>
                </li> 


                <li style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3)" class="px-3 py-3 my-1">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img/baseline_work2.png"> 
                  <p class="text-light">Tester de Software na 
                    <a href="https://www.demaria.com.br/site/" class="acustom">DeMaria</a>
                  </p>
                  <small class="text-light font-italic" >Período: 2017 - Atualmente</small>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
    </main>
                <style>
              body, p, html , h1, nav, section, main, img{
                margin: 0;

              }
            </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `margin: 0;` to `margin: 0 !important;`

This may fix it, but the correct way would be removing 'margin' from the class that is being applied to this element.

Comment: Beleza haha unfortunately It didn't work :( I used `marign: 0 !important;`<br/> but the behavior's page is the same

Comment: Cara, aplica esta classe em geral, como nosso amigo falou lá em baixo, verifica se é margin mesmo e tenta ir tirando classe por classe de css até descobrir qual é o problema. Espero que isso possa te ajudar!

Comment: so I found the problem, It was on section tag that had the "class="my-4", your answer helped me to see that, thanks

Comment: Fico feliz em saber que pude te ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all the tags at the top and replace them with *. An asterisk means all the tags within the html document. I rewrote your code in this manner:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

It would be really helpful to solve this if you can include the html code as well if my code didn't work